# LWC Datatable not returning data

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to perform the following:
Create a lwc that will render related records in a datatable:
Make LWC available for quick action.
So basically have a QA on the Parent record that when selected will display child records in a datatable.

I have tried following the documentation here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation
But all that renders is the column header in the datatable.  Is this because I am not pulling from the parent but a child.  If there is documentation or an example somewhere please just point me in that direction.
P

Comment: What specifically have you tried? You're going to need to write some Apex to make this work.

Comment: You can't have LWC component in the quick action. You need to wrap LWC in the Aura and use aura in the quick action. If you can paste the html and js code of your lwc , then we may be able to help why lwc datable doesn't render the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the reply. My Aura Component was incorrect. needed to add recordId="{!v.recordId}"